# 5.25" internal blu-ray drive manafactures

Tags: blu-ray

I'm looking for a list of 5.25" internal blu-ray drive manufactures. I'm specifically talking about manufactures that sell what they manufacture. Not re-branded stuff. For example seasonic manufactures there own power supplies, and sells them to other companies to re-brand. But they don't sell power supplies that they don't make.

Comment: While this list might be useful to you (and a *slim* chance for a few other people), this list would not be set in stone.  It could change at any point.   I dont think it is appropriate for this site.  That being said, I am fairly certain Sony does manufacturer their own Blu-Ray drives.

Comment: One such list is Amazon.com.  If you're looking for products sold in the marketplace, go to the marketplace.  Pick a few major retailers and search for blu-ray on their site.